# Global access to view for using headlink plugin Zend Framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, viewmodel, view-helpers

How can I access the `headLink` view helper from a global perspective, maybe for example here:

```
        public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
        {
            $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();        
            $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
            $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
            $app          = $e->getTarget();
            $locator      = $app->getServiceManager();
            $view         = $locator->get('Zend\View\View');
            $view->plugin()->headLink()->appendStylesheet('img.css');        
        }
```

Another great example would be if I used an Event that fired off a custom class which could access the view helper as well. I imagine Id need access to the `application` class.

Please assist any way possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
        {                
            $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
            $headLinkHelper = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('HeadLink');
            $headLinkHelper->appendStylesheet('img.css');
        }
```